# Load Partial view after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that contains a dropdown on load, when the dropdown value is changed it loads a partial view blow the dropdown containing an input form. This works correctly.

Now when i open the page, but the dropdown value has already been selected i need to load that same partial view.

But when i do this the entire layout get's loaded again and not my partial view. 
Both these post back to the same action. Does anyone have an idea.

Please look at the images below for the outputs.

```js
$('#DbDropdown').on('change', function (evt) {
                LoadBody();
            });

            $(window).bind("load", function () {
                var e = document.getElementById("DbDropdown");
                var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                if (text != "Please select")
                { 
                    LoadBody();
                }                
            });

            function LoadBody()
            {
                var url = "GetHeader";
                var $Detail = $("#HeaderSection")
                $.ajax({
                    data: $("#PRForm").serialize(),
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url: url,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $Detail.html(result);
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert(ex);
                    }
                });
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@model PRHeaderVM

<section>
    <h2>Purchase Requesition @Model.PrNumber
     </h2>
    <form asp-action="SubmitPR" role="form" id="PRForm" style="width: 100%;top:0;right:0;left: 10px; bottom:10px" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PrNumber)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Status)
        <div style="margin-top : 10px; position:fixed;top:50px;right:50px;width : 150px">
            @if (Model.Status == 1)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_CreateButtonTemplate");
            }
            @if (Model.Status == 2)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_ApproveButtonTemplate");
            }
        </div>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 40px;">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Company</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <select id="DbDropdown" asp-for="CompanyID" asp-items="@Model.Companies" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Please select</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="HeaderSection">
            </div>            
        </div>
</form>
</section>
```

**Selecting the value myself**

[Selecting the value myself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oReKm.png)

**Value loaded from model**
[Value loaded from model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDfcb.png)

Comment: I deleted my answer because I didn't understand the problem.  It sounds like your backend program `GetHeader` is the problem. You need to investigate why it doesn't return the HTML you expect.

Comment: I also thought so but it doesn't seem to call the action at all when i call it from my onload?

Comment: Found the issue myself and gave an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by Specifying the url for the on form load ajax call.

```js
function LoadPRBody(url) {                
                var $Detail = $("#HeaderSection");
                alert($("#PRForm").serialize().toString());
                $.ajax({
                    data: $("#PRForm").serialize(),
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url: url,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $Detail.html(result);
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert(ex);
                    }
                });
            }

            $('#DbDropdown').on('change', function (evt) {
                LoadPRBody("GetHeader");
            });

            $(window).on("load", function () {
                var val = $('#DbDropdown').val();
                alert(val);
                if (val != 0) {
                    LoadPRBody("@Url.Action("GetHeader", "Requests")");
                }
            });
```

The issue seemed to be that the url was not being loaded correctly that the point when the ajax reqest was made, thus not knowing in which controller to look for the action.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below should do it (was deleted, see comments). One more input:

*As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated.*
You are using on your first line .on and on the 4th line .bind. .on has replaced .live and .bind so you should use .on on every element for future development.

```
$('#DbDropdown') *.on* ('change', function (evt) {
   LoadBody();
});

$(window) *.bind* ("load", function () {
```

Comment: Thanks this is my first site so i'm still learning. Below answer did not rectify the issue.

Comment: Ah your problem is that the wrong content is assigned? On the first picture you are having other form fields as in the second picture? I haven't understand your problem first I think...

Comment: Correct the first image is what i expect to get back, but it should be populated with data as it i opened from existing data, but it is not returning the correct content.

both options call the exact same action that return the exact same partial view.

Comment: Are you sure that your ajax call does give you the right content? It makes no sense, that the same ajax call should give you other content... You have also missed a ; after var $Detail = $("#HeaderSection"). Have you tested if you receive the correct content using content.log(data) one time? Also have a look what $("#PRForm").serialize() gives you on both calls.
You should use $( document ).ready(function() instead $(window).bind("load") and you are using plain javascript and jQuery. You should decide yourself for one. var e = document.getElementById("DbDropdown"); --> $('#DbDropdown').val()

Comment: I had a look and the output from the two are the same if i show it the serialize method in an alert